# WebView with a muted, autoplaying video pauses other audio sources

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a webview which opens a page with a video that starts muted. Something like this:

`<video autoplay muted playsinline>`

This causes other apps playing audio in the background to pause, for instance Spotify. This is not a great user experience, as we do not want our users interrupted before they actively decide to listen to the audio of the video by clicking it. Is there any configuration we can do to the `WebView` to fix this? Or do we have to accept that this is in the hands of Google and wait for a Chrome WebView fix?

[Test page](http://view-source:http://www.nilsenlabs.com/vg/muted-autoplay.html) if you want to try and reproduce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to invoke `settings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(true);` on a `WebSettings` object. It should solve your issue.

Works fine on Nexus 5X (Android 8.1.0) with Spotify in the background.